# Geolocation error when url has ip

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, secure-context

I had an webapp that uses Geolocation, but, when url has ip, the Geolocation doesn't work.

I catch this error: PositionError {code: 1, message: "Only secure origins are allowed ...

Comment: Secure origins are probably only your local machine and HTTPS hosts

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Comment: @Ricky - You should just post that as an answer, with a summary, something along the lines of "You need to enable a HTTPS\secure connection with your webapp."

Answer (score 1):

> Chrome no longer supports obtaining the user's location using the
>   HTML5 Geolocation API from pages delivered by non-secure connections.

User location is considered sensitive data, that's why Chrome enforced serving your website in a [secure context](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/) (HTTPS) in order to use the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) in their browser.

More info: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only